# Mongo java driver upgrade from 3.12.1 to 4.2.3 throwing method/class not found execptions on deployment

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I have java application based on mongo server 4.2 and component versions are as follows

```
spring-boot 2.2.5.RELEASE
spring-data-mongodb2.2.5.RELEASE
mongo-java-driver3.12.1
```

I updated spring boot to 2.5.8 hence made few changes to update dependencies as follow

```
spring-boot2.5.8
spring-starter-parent2.5.8
spring-data-mongodb 3.2.3
mongodb-driver-core 4.2.3

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

As I used newly added

```
**import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;**
```

i.e mordern API using mongo-java driver 3.12.1 I updated to mongodb-driver-sync 4.2.3

I resolved all compilation errors but on deployment got errors like method not found for **getSrvHost()** on further debugging found that old dependency of **mongo-java-driver 3.3.0** was already present in project

I excluded that dependency and above issue got resolved now no old dependency is present but still getting following error without using legacy API approach

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
```

Completely stuck at this point in driver and spring upgrade process, without using com.mongodb.MongoClient in entire project it is throwing error on deployment.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended use [spring-boot-starter-parent](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent) as `<parent>` to use compatible versions.

Just add the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` dependency and it has all the necessary MongoDB drivers. 
Remove from `pom.xml`: `spring-data-mongodb`, `mongodb-driver-core`, `spring-starter-parent`

**Note:** Always use the last version, since `2.5.8` has [3 vulnerabilities](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.8)

### pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

...
<dependencies>
    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image: Dependency Hierarchy]